# How to auto-resize an Angular grid when accordion is expanded inside the grid?

Tags: angular

I am trying to insert an expandable accordion inside of Angular grid. When I click on the accordion the grid hight is limited and cannot see all the content inside the accordion.

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4">
  <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="4" [rowspan]="1">
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
    <mat-accordion class="w-100-p">
      <mat-expansion-panel>
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
           <mat-panel-title>
               Add aditional contact details
           </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <div class="section pb-48">     
          <div>
          <div class="projects_client_style" flex="20">Estimated End Date:</div>
          <div>some sort of text for Manager</div>
          </div>
       </mat-expansion-panel>
      </mat-accordion>
    </div>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ry9yry

I would like to have minimum height as much as possible for each tile. I would like the grid to expand as well when accordion is expended.

Also I use `fxLayoutAlign="center center"` but I cannot center the first row where One, Two, Three, Four and Five is written.

I am new to Angular. I would appreciate if you can show me how to make it work.

Comment: the accordian on expanding is taking up the space it needs... it is the tiles, that are controlled by padding, margins etc. so each time the accordion opens, you gotta change other divs - if you want a real world solution, you gotta go with divs you can control - not the mat-grid-tiles; some gurus may have other solutions

Comment: thank you I will do it with divs not with mat-grid tiles